# How to continuosly loop over array values from another loop?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I've got a array of numbers for example :

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

And number of constants:

```
TITLES = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

When I iterate over `a` I want to get a title for each item like this :

```
- iterating over a, first item (1) get title 'a'
- iterating over a, first item (2) get title 'b'
- iterating over a, first item (3) get title 'c'
- iterating over a, first item (4) get title 'd'
- iterating over a, first item (5) get title 'a'
- iterating over a, first item (6) get title 'b'
```

So when I run over titles start from the begining, this is what I have now :

```
a.each_with_index do |m, i|
  if TITLES[i].nil?
    title = TITLES[(i - TITLES.length)]
  else
    title = TITLES[i]
  end
end
```

But this doesn't work unfortunately I get a `nil` title for the last item of `a`. How can I make this work?

Comment: Do you always have 4 constants?  If so you can slice a into chunks of 4 then iterate over them

Comment: Try `title = TITLES[i % TITLES.length]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind-of-obvious way uses [#each_with_index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)

```
a.each_with_index do |x, i|
  p [x, TITLES[i % TITLES.length]]
end
```

Or, try something like this...

```
a.zip(TITLES*3).each do |x, y|
  p [x, y]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [`cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-cycle) methods like this:

```
a.zip(TITLES.cycle).each do |x, title|
  p [x, title]
end

# Output:
# [1, "a"]
# [2, "b"]
# [3, "c"]
# [4, "d"]
# [5, "a"]
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
TITLES = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

t_length = TITLES.length

a.each_with_index do |item, index|
  t_index = index % t_length
  title = TITLES[t_index]
  puts "item: #{item} - title: #{title}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
TITLES = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

TITLES = TITLES + TITLES + TITLES

 (a.zip TITLES).each do |p, q|
    puts "======#{p}==#{q}======"
 end
```